# How to download xml file from ftp using following android code?

Tags: android

I used following code for downloading XML file from ftp to android phone memory using that i able to connect ftp but while retrieving XML to local memory it is giving following exception 07-19 15:01:03.721: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
 please help somebody thank you,

**Java class**

```
private void fnfileDownloadBuf()
{

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
    //client.connect("ftp://ftp.qualityinaction.net/QIA/Questions/Airlines/");
    client.connect("ftp.qualityinaction.net");
    client.login("qualityinaction.net","password");
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    //
    // The remote filename to be downloaded.
    //
   // String filename = "/QIA/Questions/Airlines/index.xml";
    String filename = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "/index.xml";
   // String filename = "/QIA/Questions/Airlines/index.xml";
    File file = new File(filename);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //
    // Download file from FTP server
    //
    //client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);
    client.retrieveFile("/QIA/Questions/Airlines/index.xml;type=i", fos);
   // client.retrieveFile( getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "/index.xml", fos);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**manifest XML file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

**Exception**

```
exception 07-19 15:01:03.721: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: copy and paste the error in google search box

Comment: thanks for response,i tried I'm not getting anything can u please check and tell me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you have to use passive mode corrected code as shown below..

```
** Java Code **

FTPClient ObjFtpCon = new FTPClient();
                try
                {
                    ObjFtpCon.connect(strIp);
                    if (ObjFtpCon.login(strFtpUser, strFtpPwd))
                    {
                        ObjFtpCon.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                        ObjFtpCon.cwd("/QIA/Questions/Hotel/");
                        String[] strArrQuesFiles=ObjFtpCon.listNames();
                        int intcnt=0;
                        boolean blnresult = false;
                        File objfile=new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Questions");
                        if(!objfile.exists())objfile.mkdirs();
                        objfile=null;
                        for(intcnt=0;intcnt<strArrQuesFiles.length;intcnt++)
                        {
                            objfile=new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "/Questions/" + strArrQuesFiles[intcnt]);
                            objfile.createNewFile();
                            //ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                            FileOutputStream objFos=new FileOutputStream(objfile);
                            blnresult=ObjFtpCon.retrieveFile(strArrQuesFiles[intcnt] , objFos);
                            objFos.close();
                        }

                        // boolean result = con.storeFile("/QIA/Response/test/Responses.xml", in);
                        if (blnresult) dlgAlert.setMessage("Questions Are Successfully Downloaded").create().show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                try
                {
                    ObjFtpCon.logout();
                    ObjFtpCon.disconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```